# Free camera moves without user interaction and behaves weird

Tags: camera

The free camera (SHIFT + F) worked perfectly fine in previous blender versions. However now I updated to 2.78c and made very bad experience.

The camera automatically keeps moving slowly in the last direction where you pushed the mouse and behaves extremly weird. Sometimes it does not move at all right after I activate it.

What is going on, is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Check if in the preferences > Input Walk/Fly mode is set to Walk by default as probably you're activating Fly mode while looking for the other one.

Comment: After I started my computer today it is working as expected and I am not sure why.